# Using DataGrip, is there a way to display each element of structs and arrays implicitly separated without directly selecting/exploding each one?

Tags: google-bigquery, datagrip

I am querying Google BigQuery databases using JetBrains' DataGrip. I love the UI in many ways, but one thing I'd like to know is if there is a more friendly way to see structs and arrays.
I hate the BigQuery WebUI for many reasons, but the one thing I like is the way they implicitly render structs and arrays.

```
select struct("s1","s2","s3")
     , array(select "a1" union all select "a2" union all select "a3")
 union all
select struct("s4","s5","s6")
     , array(select "a4" union all select "a5" union all select "a6")
```

To clarify with images, I like the following in BigQuery:
[image: BigQuery implicit rendering]

DataGrip is harder to read:
[image: DataGrip symbolized rendering]

Comment: can you post two images to compare and explicitly show what is that you like and not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll finally be able to see your structs in the following DataGrip 2022.3 release.

Next steps:

- [DBE-16175](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16175/Support-editing-tables-with-BigQuery-struct-and-array-data-types) Support editing tables with BigQuery struct and array
  data types
- [DBE-16173](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16173/Better-Data-Viewer-presentationlayout-for-hierarchical-data-types-struct-array-json) Better Data Viewer presentation/layout for
  hierarchical data types (struct, array, json)
- [DBE-16176](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16176/Erase-extra-Data-Viewer-border-when-showing-flattened-hierarchical-data-struct-array-json) Erase
  extra Data Viewer border when showing flattened hierarchical data
  (struct, array, json)

Here is an example how it would be displayed in DataGrip:
[image: BQ Structs]

Comment: Yes, it will be released in 2022.3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it will look in DataGrip, but try below

```
select format('%T', col1) col1, format('%T', col2) col2 from (
  select struct("s1","s2","s3") col1
  , array(select "a1" union all select "a2" union all select "a3") col2
  union all
  select struct("s4","s5","s6") 
  , array(select "a4" union all select "a5" union all select "a6")
)
```

i am using this trick some times within BigQuery Console, to have even better view so results are more compact and easier to swallow

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, but this isn't a SQL question, it's a DataGrip settings customization question. I don't want to have to constantly add formatting to my queries. I want to use DataGrip, and I want the results to be formatted along the lines of what I see in the BigQuery Web UI. Does that make sense?